# What is the preferred way to do site templates and themes with Wicket?

Tags: java, templates, themes, wicket

I'm just learning Wicket, and Googling yields different results about how to theme/template a site using Wicket. It appears that the common methods are:

- Markup Inheritance ([description](http://jroller.com/pKulak/entry/markup_inheritance_with_wicket))
- Borders ([description](http://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/consistent-page-layout-using-borders.html))
- Reusable Panels ([description](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t60926.html))
- Fragments ([description](http://wicket.apache.org/examplefragments.html))

**What is the best practices / "right" way to do this in Wicket?** Or do these different methods each have specific kinds of uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at wicket localizer. I think "styles" is what you are looking for.

So if you have only one locale and you want to make "styles" for the Home page, you create:

- Home.html
- Home_style1.html
- Home_styleanother.html

Wicket styles are also applicable to the strings and others resources.

See [Localization and Skinning of Applications](http://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/localization-and-skinning-of-applications.html).